# How to ignore delimiter for certain rows of records while reading a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I've got a two column CSV with a name and a number. Some people's name use commas, for example HO,inc. This comma breaks the CSV format, since it's interpreted as a new column. how to handle this in python .

```
123,'""HO,inc""'
456,'""baba,the""'
```

By doing:

```
output = writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator='\n')
```

### My expected output is:

```
123 | Ho inc
456 | baba the
```

But, on the contrary, my current output is:

```
123 | HO | inc
```

With my solution, the values of 2nd column are split into 2 distinct ones.
I'm getting 3 columns, while expecting 2 columns.

I'm new to python.
How I can solve it? Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, pudianna. It's not clear to me exactly what you expect. Will you please edit your question to clearly show how many columns you expect from that single line/row of CSV, and what text you expect in each column? Thank you.

Comment: updated , hope its clear now

Comment: your thread title mentions "reading csv" but your question only describes "writing csv". Do you really need both? I would consider writing this data in JSON format, or at the very least, .tsv format, instead of .csv, if possible, to make your life easier. But it depends on the exact circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your quoting.  Using two double quotes says "this quote mark is part of the data", so there really are three fields.  If you want the quotes to protect a single field, then just use one double quote:

```
123,"HO, inc"
456,"baba, the"
```

That CSV file has 2 columns.

```
import csv

for line in csv.reader(open('x.csv')):
    print(len(line), "fields")
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
2 fields
['123', 'HO, inc']
2 fields
['456', 'baba, the']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you cannot modify your .csv file, which is in the (messed-up) form:

```
123,"""HO,inc"""
456,"""baba,the"""
```

To obtain the desired pandas DataFrame (or, at least, the output you said you wanted in your original question, so without the comma between words in the second column):

```
  First_col Second_col
0       123     HO inc
1       456   baba the
```

Here is my way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

elems = []

with open('your_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        col2 = row[1].split(',', 1)    #divide the 2nd column into parts, after the 1st comma
        if len(col2) > 1:              #link the 1st and 2nd parts, if the split returns more than 1 elem 
            col2 = col2[0].strip() + ' ' + col2[1].strip() 
        else:
            col2 = col2[0].strip()                                 
        elems.append([row[0], col2])   #insert the row to elems list


df = pd.DataFrame(elems, columns=['First_col', 'Second_col']) #create a new DataFrame 
df['Second_col'] = df['Second_col'].str.replace('"', '')     #remove extra quotes
```

---

While to obtain the same DataFrame but with the words of *Second_col* separated by a comma...

```
  First_col Second_col
0       123     HO, inc
1       456   baba, the
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv
elems = []

with open('your_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if ',' in row[1]:
            col2 = row[1].split(',', 1)
            col2 = col2[0].strip() + ', ' + col2[1].strip()
        else:
            col2 = row[1].strip()
        elems.append([row[0], col2])

df = pd.DataFrame(elems, columns=['First_col', 'Second_col'])
df['Second_col'] = df['Second_col'].str.replace('"', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is useful for you:

```
    def read_csv_file(filepath="sample.csv") -> list:
        # open file
        with open(filepath,"r") as f:
           lines = f.readlines()

       # remove unnecessary characters in a line 
       to_clear = lambda line : line.replace("\'",'').replace('"','').replace("\n","").split(',')
       new_lines = [to_clear(line) for line in lines]

       # create certain line format
       to_list =  lambda el:[el[0],' '.join(el[1:])]
       new_lines = [to_list (el) for el in new_lines] 
    
       return new_lines
```

After that you can load it to pandas with columns, if you want.

Have a nice day,

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your CSV is messed up.  You need to correct what's there before you can truly treat it as CSV.

Based on your limited sample data, it looks to me like `'""` and `""'` should each be replaced with a single double quote (`"`).

In CSV terms, this will turn the two fields of `'""HO,inc""'` (`'"HO` and `inc"'`) into the single field, `"HO,inc"`. `"HO, inc"` will be read by Python's csv module as the string `HO, inc`.

*You said you wanted `Ho inc` which is missing the orignal comma. Was that a typo?*

To fix the CSV, first:

```py
# Fix out-of-place single quotes and doubled-double quotes

f_in = open("input.csv")
f_out = open("input_fixed.csv", "w")

for line in f_in:
    line = line.replace('\'""', '"')
    line = line.replace('""\'', '"')
    f_out.write(line)

f_out.close()
f_in.close()
```

which gives me the following input_fixed.csv:

```
123,"HO,inc"
456,"baba,the"
```

The single double quotes for each second field exclude the commas inside from being read as a delimiter... those commas are just data, now.

Then, process the CSV:

```py
# Deal with CSV as normal

with open("input_fixed.csv", newline="") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

which prints:

```py
['123', 'HO,inc']
['456', 'baba,the']
```

If you want the commas removed from the second field, handle that after the bad quotes have been fixed.  Maybe something like:

```py
for row in reader:
    field_2 = row[1].replace(",", " ")
    row[1]= field_2
    ...
```